# 301 or 302 redirect for site which will have no content for a year?

Tags: 301-redirect, search

I have a domain which will not have any actual content for a year or maybe more, and I want to redirect for the time being. Should I opt for a 301 or 302 redirect? The site is for an academic research project, and the redirect will point to an associated info page on our institution's main site. My main concern lies with how any redirect might affect our Google ranking, though we do not expect a Google search to be the main means by which users actually arrive at our site.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a 302, as 301 is a permanent redirect that indicates to browsers and search engines "this site has moved over here, and isn't coming back". [Chrome and Firefox cache a 301 with no expiration by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130422/how-long-do-browsers-cache-http-301s), meaning users encountering one *may* never again see the site, even years later.

If you don't expect users to stumble across the domain, you might also consider a `503 Service Unavailable` response rather than redirecting.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I knew 301 was permanent, but I wasn't sure how long 'temporary' would really mean in the case of 302... I guess a year is still 'temporary'! I was unaware of the Chrome/Firefox behaviour, thanks for that info.

Comment: @ChrisM If you know roughly when the site'll open up, you could consider putting an `Expires` and a `Retry-After` header on the 302/503. Or just put a week/month-long value in there so the engines keep checking back periodically.

Comment: Is there a possibility that the _target_ of the 302 redirect might be penalized? I don't own that site, and don't want to inadvertently cause problems for it with respect to indexing, SEO, etc (sorry for delayed follow-up).

Comment: @ChrisM If you could damage someone else's site via 302s it'd be widely abused. Shouldn't be an issue, it's a common use case.

Comment: Thanks, good point. Just wanted to make 100% sure. Set it up now, all good.